# Grouping lines considering intersections of each line using python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, opencv, geometry

There are 5 lines. I want to group them considering whether they intersect or not by limiting to the two end points of each line.

**I want to get the logic for any of the lines, not being limited to the given scenario.**
Array of 5 lines (coordinates of end points).

```
lines_all = [[(1, 10), (5, 10)],[(3, 5), (5, 5)],[(3, 10), (3, 13)],[(5,10),(5,13)],[(3,13),(4,13)]]
```

[image: 5 lines]
Then finally I want to get the following array list.

```
result = [[[(1, 10), (5, 10)], [(3, 10), (3, 13)],[(3, 13), (4, 13)]], [[(1, 10), (5, 10)], [(5, 10), (5, 13)]],[(3, 5), (5, 5)]]
```

[image: final lines]

Comment: You can check whether a point (x, y) is on a line (a, b, c) with the dot product: (x, y) lies on (a, b, c) if and only if the inner product of (x, y, 1) and (a, b, c) is 0. The line represented as (a, b, c) is the line ax + by + c = 0, or in slope intercept form, y = -(x+c)/b (with b not equal to 0, of course). Note also that you can get the line (a, b, c) from the endpoints with a cross product; the line from (x, y) to (x', y') is (x, y, 1) x (x', y', 1).

Comment: So putting it all together, (3, 10) is on the line that connects (1, 10) and (5, 10) if and only if the inner product of (3, 10, 1) and (1, 10, 1) x (5, 10, 1) is 0. (Though this does assume that the line extends past the endpoints...)

Answer (score 1):

To find all line segment intersections, you can use [Bentley-Ottmann algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm).

Arbitrary found [Python implementation](https://github.com/ideasman42/isect_segments-bentley_ottmann)

Comment: Huh, that's really cool! Didn't know that algorithm was around.